# Importing XML Data into PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, import

I have the following XML file that I need to bring into a Table in Postgresql.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="KenWiens@205.138.249.107" start="2021-07-05T22:48:17.866Z">
  <ls>
    <destination value="/" />
    <files>
      <file>
        <filename value="ALL_ELAN_CLAIMS_20180601_20210531.txt" />
        <type value="-" />
        <size value="202286572" />
        <modification value="2021-06-03T15:45:25.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rw-rw-rw-" />
        <owner value="user" />
        <group value="group" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="ALL_ELAN_CLAIMS_20180701_20210630.txt" />
        <type value="-" />
        <size value="208553108" />
        <modification value="2021-07-03T12:16:37.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rw-rw-rw-" />        <owner value="user" />
        <group value="group" />
      </file>
```

Each set of filename, type, size, modification should be in a single row in the new table. I have not been able to accomplish this using the examples posted on-line. Could you help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add a valid xml document to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [xmltable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING). Below is an illustration. Pls. note that I have added a few missing closing tags to your XML document to make it valid.

```sql
with t(xml_value) as
(
select
$XML$<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="KenWiens@205.138.249.107" start="2021-07-05T22:48:17.866Z">
  <ls>
    <destination value="/" />
    <files>
      <file>
        <filename value="ALL_ELAN_CLAIMS_20180601_20210531.txt" />
        <type value="-" />
        <size value="202286572" />
        <modification value="2021-06-03T15:45:25.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rw-rw-rw-" />
        <owner value="user" />
        <group value="group" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="ALL_ELAN_CLAIMS_20180701_20210630.txt" />
        <type value="-" />
        <size value="208553108" />
        <modification value="2021-07-03T12:16:37.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rw-rw-rw-" />        <owner value="user" />
        <group value="group" />
      </file>
    </files>
  </ls>
</session>
$XML$::xml
)
select x.* from t, xmltable 
(
  xmlnamespaces ('http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0' as ns),
  '/ns:session/ns:ls/ns:files/ns:file' 
  passing xml_value
  columns 
    filename text path 'ns:filename/@value',
    type text path 'ns:type/@value',
    size integer path 'ns:size/@value',
    modification timestamptz path 'ns:modification/@value'
) x;

/* result:
filename                             |type|size     |modification       |
-------------------------------------+----+---------+-------------------+
ALL_ELAN_CLAIMS_20180601_20210531.txt|-   |202286572|2021-06-03 18:45:25|
ALL_ELAN_CLAIMS_20180701_20210630.txt|-   |208553108|2021-07-03 15:16:37|
*/
```

Comment: That does work, but the XML is much longer and I only posted a small piece. I tried a sample that I saw posted that would read the XML in from a file:                                  
          SELECT (xpath('//session/ls/files/file/filename', x))[1]::text::int AS FN,
         (xpath('//row/size', x))[1]::text::int AS Size,
         (xpath('//row/modification', x))[1]::text::int AS Mod
      
  FROM unnest(xpath('//row', pg_read_file('c:/elan/log/filelist.xml')::xml)) x;

Comment: Do not worry about size, Postgres handles megabytes of inline data with ease. Why not try a parameterized version like `with t(xml_value) as (select :xml_text::xml) select ...` and `prepare` then `execute` it with the whole xml file contents as an argument?